# UIButton + italic font = clipping

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, clipping, italic

The problem is that UIButton clips title tail (for about 1-2 pixels at the end) when I use italic font like Helvetica Oblique with size bigger than 13. Does anybody know a solution for this problem?

Comment: Set the wrap mode to something other than truncate tail.

Comment: Is the button big enough?! If you call sizeToFit *before* setting the text and font, this cannot work.

Comment: more details please, but i think your case is "no matter how wide you make a button, any text, when made italic, gets clipped in a UIButton" - if that's the case, i don't know a workaround, and it's a bug, report it

Comment: An image demonstrating the problem would also be helpful.

Comment: This is very old question. I believe that it is obsolete. To @bshirley - Yes it was no matter how wide a button.

Answer (score 2):

Subclass `UIButton` class and override setTitle with:

`- (void)setTitle:(NSString *)title forState:(UIControlState)state {
    [super setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@ ", title] forState:state];
}`

This will add additional spaces from both sides of your text. 
Easy & simple.

Comment: Good thinking. A way that's even simpler is to just put a space before and after the standard UIButton's title.

Comment: Sorry but this is not a real solution, is a workaround at best, and padding the title with spaces for solving a layout/drawing issue is something that would likely bite you in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with my script font.  Unfortunately there isn't a simple way to fix it.  I tried everything and then ended up subclassing UIButton.  You can read the details for implementation here: http://blog.tinymission.com/post/subclassing-uibutton

Basically, the easiest thing to do would be to put your own UILabel on top of the UIButton, but for me, that wouldn't work well so I subclassed UIButton.

Answer (score 0):

You can set Italic font by setting Uibutton property as

button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.italicSystemFont(ofSize: 17)

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a custom subclass of `UIButton`
2. Override method: `- (CGRect)titleRectForContentRect:(CGRect)contentRect`

Example:

```
- (CGRect)titleRectForContentRect:(CGRect)contentRect
{
    CGFloat textX = 0;
    CGFloat textY = 0;
    CGFloat textW = self.width;
    CGFloat textH = contentRect.size.height;
    return CGRectMake(textX, textY, textW, textH);
}
```